# I am making a safe, compile-time String.format(...) equivalent. An issue still persist

Tags: java, enums, abstract, abstraction, string.format

Most people understand the innate benefits that `enum` brings into a program verses the use of `int` or `String`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709175/what-are-enums-and-why-are-they-useful/4709224#4709224) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9254703/2333021) if you don't know. Anyway, I came across a problem that I wanted to solve that kind of is on the same playing field as using `int` or `String` to represent a constant instead of using an `enum`. This deals specifically with String.format(...).

With String.format, there seems to be a large opening for **programmatic error** that *isn't found at compile-time*. This can make fixing errors more complex and / or take longer.

**This was the issue for me that I set out to fix (or hack a solution). I came close, but I am not close enough.** For this problem, this is more certainly over-engineered. I understand that, but I just want to find a good compile-time solution to this, that provides the least amount of boiler-plate code.

I was writing some non-production code just to write code with the following rules.

- Abstraction was key.
- Readability was very important
- **Yet the simplest way to the above was preferred.**

I am running on...

- Java 7 / JDK 1.7
- Android Studio 0.8.2

### These are unsatisfactory

- [Is there a typesafe alternative to String.format(...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116325/is-there-a-typesafe-alternative-to-string-format)
- [How to get string.format to complain at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718190/how-to-get-string-format-to-complain-at-compile-time)

### My Solution

My solution uses the same idea that `enums` do. You should use enum types any time you need to represent a fixed set of constants...data sets where you know all possible values at compile time([docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)). The first argument in `String.format` seems to fit that bill. You know the whole string beforehand, and you can split it up into several parts (or just one), so it can be represented as a fixed set of "constants".

*By the way, my project is a simple calculator that you probably seen online already - 2 input numbers, 1 result, and 4 buttons (+, -, ×, and ÷). I also have a second duplicate calculator that has only 1 input number, but everything else is the same*

### Enum - Expression.java & DogeExpression.java

```
public enum Expression implements IExpression {

    Number1     ("%s"),
    Operator    (" %s "),
    Number2     ("%s"),
    Result      (" = %s");

    protected String defaultFormat;
    protected String updatedString = "";

    private Expression(String format) { this.defaultFormat = format; }

    // I think implementing this in ever enum is a necessary evil. Could use a switch statement instead. But it would be nice to have a default update method that you could overload if needed. Just wish the variables could be hidden.
    public <T> boolean update(T value) { 

        String replaceValue
                = this.equals(Expression.Operator)
                ? value.toString()
                : Number.parse(value.toString()).toString();

        this.updatedString = this.defaultFormat.replace("%s", replaceValue);

        return true;

    }

}
```

...and...

```
public enum DogeExpression implements IExpression {

    Total   ("Wow. Such Calculation. %s");

    // Same general code as public enum Expression

}
```

### Current Issue

**IExpression.java** - This is a **HUGE** issue. Without this fixed, my solution cannot work!!

```
public interface IExpression {

    public <T> boolean update(T Value);

    class Update {  // I cannot have static methods in interfaces in Java 7. Workaround

        public static String print() {

            String replacedString = "";

            // for (Expression expression : Expression.values()) {   // ISSUE!! Switch to this for Expression
            for (DogeExpression expression : DogeExpression.values()) {

                replacedString += expression.updatedString;

            }

            return replacedString;
        }

    }

}
```

### So Why Is This An Issues

With `IExpression.java`, this had to hacked to work with Java 7. I feel that Java 8 would have played a lot nicer with me. **However, the issue I am having is *paramount* to getting my current implementation working** The issue is that `IExpression` does not know which `enum` to iterate through. So I have to comment / uncomment code to get it to work now.

**How can I fix the above issue??**

Comment: I read twice your question and feel want to answer but I am lazy to copy so many code and try it out. Is it possible for you create a sample project just to illustrate your problem? Preferable maven project.

Comment: Is this question different from [the one you posted a few days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769455/java-string-format-compile-time-error-checking)? If so, how?

Comment: This approach is actually significantly *worse* than using `String.format`, because `Number1`, `Operator`, `Number2`, and `Result` are global state. You can't build two strings at once with this code, meaning reentrancy and threading are off the table. Furthermore, you need to write a whole new class with a ton of boilerplate for *every* format string. It doesn't even provide any additional type safety, and you can *still* screw up writing `%s` in the enums without the compiler noticing.

Comment: @user2357112 This one is more specific; however, I was wondering if I could have this question only focus on my major issue, and I could retrofit my previous question to deal with my other issue. I **think** this question could be answered correctly with one answer dealing with  the major issue, and the other answer dealing with the other issue. I think my other question is dead as is

Comment: please post more issues if you find any. I am aware of the boilerplate code. I don't like it either as much. I was thinking of adding Types for each enum constant that `%s` should be, but I feel like that might just add more boilerplate code - unless it can go in `IExpression` somehow. As far as threading right now that was not a concern. This would be single-thread only for now. You have to start somewhere. Brighter minds could take another step later

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but I think your design is fundamentally broken. When I try to fix the issues in this code, I get a horribly unwieldy reimplementation of string concatenation. There is literally no advantage over `num1 + " " + operator.getSign() + " " + num2 + " = " + total`. Any apparent reduction in complexity at the call site is due to that complexity being shifted to a non-reusable `Expression` class. None of it is any safer than string concatenation. Trying to add compile-time safety results in the whole thing becoming a wrapper around string concatenation.

Comment: Sure there is. Just not all the huge advantages that you might wish with a baked in type-safe, compile-time. I can only work with what I have. There might be ways to add safety into it. Maybe starting with `Number1     ("%s", Double.class),` and adding the needed code. By the way, my code still does not work. I know you don't like the implementation, but if my major issue can be solved I can test it more. Don't like my try. Please try another way...this is really bothering me

Comment: I am sorry but this approach is horrible, unworkable, and altogether vastly more complicated than the minor issue which it tries and fails to solve. Don't do this.

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski: I tried! I gave it an honest shot! To actually gain the compile-time safety you're after, you have to take all information about the number and type of arguments out of the format string. Splitting it into chunks with one `%s` per chunk doesn't help. After trying to improve this code for code reusability and compile-time safety for a while, the interface evolved into `new Expression().update(num1).update(" ").update(operator.getSign()).update(" ").update(num2).update(" = ").update(total).toString()`. It always goes back to string concatenation.

Comment: So you have tried a non-enum implementation for Expression? If you still have the code I would like to look at it.

Comment: By the end of it, it was just one `StringBuilder` instance variable and a bunch of wrappers around `append`. I tried generics, but since you can't take a variable number of type arguments, that ended up with types that looked like `Builder<Integer, Builder<String, Builder<Integer, Builder<Integer, String>>>>` and an awkward need to build the `Builder` from the end of the string to the front. [Here's what that looked like when I realized I could only add types at the front of the chain.](http://pastebin.com/BUUpBFwj)

Comment: Not an answer, but FindBugs Eclise plugin catches these errors

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

---

```
public enum Operator {
    addition("+"),
    subtraction("-"),
    multiplication("x"),
    division("÷");

    private final String expressed;
    private Operator(String expressed) { this.expressed = expressed; }

    public String expressedAs() { return this.expressed; }
}
```

---

```
public class ExpressionBuilder {
    private Number n1;
    private Number n2;
    private Operator o1;
    private Number r;
    public void setN1(Number n1) { this.n1 = n1; }
    public void setN2(Number n2) { this.n2 = n2; }
    public void setO1(Operator o1) { this.o1 = o1; }
    public void setR(Number r) { this.r = r; }
    public String build() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(format(n1));
        sb.append(o1.expressedAs());
        sb.append(format(n2));
        sb.append(" = ");
        sb.append(format(r));
        return sb.toString();
    }
    private String format(Number n) {
        return n.toString(); // Could use java.text.NumberFormat 
    }
}
```